# Is go.mod in Go the same thing as package.json in JavaScript (node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, go

I am currently learning Go & it mentions using `go.mod` for dependency management. When using node, package.json files are used for dependency management, so is `go.mod` the same thing as something like `npm init -y`?

Comment: Yes and no. You can find [all the answers you are looking for here](https://go.dev/ref/mod). There are some differences on how to use `go mod` and `npm`. Note that if you want your module to be shared, you will have to define a module name with an accessible URL where you store your repository. But `go mod` helps you package your code and its dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. **go mod init** will create go.mod file. **go mod tidy**( like npn install )  will pull the dependency in the go.mod file, **go get** will pull single dependency(like npn install ...), see more detail on official site.

> https://go.dev/ref/mod